# Validating Multiple edittext and showing edittext.setError("String");

Tags: java, android, validation, android-edittext

I am trying to validate some edittext. I Made 7 edittexts. Phone number ,First name , Last name , Pickup Address, Postal Code, Pickup time, Number of products. As u can see i made 7 edittexts and I want to validate them so that when i press the button to go to next page it does all the database posting and getting on that button. I've already made a method (public void addInfo) and now i am adding the validations on the View.OnClick implemented methods.  Here is my Code i wrote for validations.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == nextbuttonjava) {


            if(phnumberjava.getText().toString().length() < 10)
            {

                phnumberjava.setError("Invalid Phone Number");
            }
            if(firstnamejava.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            {
                firstnamejava.setError("Whats your first name?");
            }
            if(lastnamejava.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            {
                lastnamejava.setError("Whats your last name?");
            }
            if(pickupaddressjava.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            {
                pickupaddressjava.setError("Enter your address");
            }
            if(postalcodejava.getText().toString().length() < 6)
            {
                postalcodejava.setError("Invalid postal code");
            }
            if(pickuptimejava.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            {
                pickuptimejava.setError("Enter pickuptime");
            }
            if(numberstuffjava.getText().toString().length() == 0) {


                numberstuffjava.setError("Enter number of clothes");
            }
            else
            {
                addInfo();
                Intent nextpageintent = new Intent(Afterfullscreen.this, Extrainformation.class);
                startActivity(nextpageintent);
            }



        }
    }
```

---

I Want that every If statement should be true to make the else work so the intent works and i go to the other activity. But its not the scene here. Only the phone number works good(If i enter the phone number below 10 digits it shows the error and it doesn't run else part). My main concern is that I Have 7 edittexts and Even if one If statement goes true then the else shouldn't be running and i shouldn't go to next intent with posting incomplete data on my database.I Want that even if any of the edittexts if statement goes wrong i should get an error (eg, numberstuffjava.setError("Input Something");.

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: try replacing the ".lenght == 0" with the ".isempty()" (Sent to fast) For the other thing of checking every each and going on only if all is fine, create a boolean "boolean error = false;". In every if add "error = true;". at the end instead of an "else", add an "if(!error){ //go on }

Comment: replace the == 0 with == null

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley isEmpty() for the firstname and the lastname. And then for postal code the digits (integers) should be below 6 
so the < 6 is oky?

Comment: yes, I post an answer because in the comment it is really confusing. Lemme know :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley the boolean error = false; You are trying to do here is that if the error = true; then the else statement will work otherwise  the errors. But if one if statement returns true; then the else will work aswell because the value of boolean error is true and then all the other if's will be ignored as usual

Comment: Check my answer below. The "error" is initialized as false because there are no errors. Every time you enter in an "if", it means there is an error, so error become true. At the end, as u see I have the if ( ! error ) which means "if ( error == false )" (probably you didn't see the ! in the comment couse of the small font)

Comment: Thank you everybody! Specially @PierGiorgioMisley That else if worked like perfectly good! Seriously i was waiting on some people to tell me how can i (Probably my teacher who taught me android) and then i just decided to ask here. Didn't expect this much of a good replies from you guys. Really Thank you everybody!

Comment: Welcome! remember to accept one of the answers below as the solution so the next one having your same problem can find easily the answer :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley done! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == nextbuttonjava) {
        boolean error = false;

        if(phnumberjava.getText().toString().length() < 10)
        {
            error = true;
            phnumberjava.setError("Invalid Phone Number");
        }
        if(firstnamejava.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            error = true;
            firstnamejava.setError("Whats your first name?");
        }
        if(lastnamejava.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            error = true;
            lastnamejava.setError("Whats your last name?");
        }
        if(pickupaddressjava.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            error = true;
            pickupaddressjava.setError("Enter your address");
        }
        if(postalcodejava.getText().toString().length() < 6)
        {
            error = true;
            postalcodejava.setError("Invalid postal code");
        }
        if(pickuptimejava.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            error = true;
            pickuptimejava.setError("Enter pickuptime");
        }
        if(numberstuffjava.getText().toString().isEmpty()) 
        {
            error = true;
            numberstuffjava.setError("Enter number of clothes");
        }
        if(!error)
        {
            addInfo();
            Intent nextpageintent = new Intent(Afterfullscreen.this, Extrainformation.class);
            startActivity(nextpageintent);
        } else {
             //manage error case here
        }
    }
}
```

another option could be this:

```
if (v == nextbuttonjava) {

    if(phnumberjava.getText().toString().length() < 10)
    {
        phnumberjava.setError("Invalid Phone Number");
    }
    else if(firstnamejava.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        firstnamejava.setError("Whats your first name?");
    }
    else if(lastnamejava.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        lastnamejava.setError("Whats your last name?");
    }
    else if(pickupaddressjava.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        pickupaddressjava.setError("Enter your address");
    }
    else if(postalcodejava.getText().toString().length() < 6)
    {
        postalcodejava.setError("Invalid postal code");
    }
    else if(pickuptimejava.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        pickuptimejava.setError("Enter pickuptime");
    }
    else if(numberstuffjava.getText().toString().isEmpty()) 
    {
        numberstuffjava.setError("Enter number of clothes");
    }
    else 
    {
        addInfo();
        Intent nextpageintent = new Intent(Afterfullscreen.this, Extrainformation.class);
        startActivity(nextpageintent);
    }
    else
    {
         //manage error case here
    }
}
```

In this way you check any case with the `else if`. I prefer the first solution because it's more "flexible".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(phnumberjava.getText().toString().length() < 10)
        {

            phnumberjava.setError("Invalid Phone Number");
return "Error message";
        }

else {
    return null;
}
```

return like this in each and every if condition. If the return statement is null, then all if conditions are true. else show the error message returned

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, you can try the following logic. Here, you can be assured that all the error messages will be shown:

```
if (v == nextbuttonjava) {
            boolean validated = true;

            if(phnumberjava.getText().toString().length() < 10) 
            { 
                phnumberjava.setError("Invalid Phone Number"); 
                validated = false;
            } 
            if(firstnamejava.getText().toString().length() == 0) 
            { 
                firstnamejava.setError("Whats your first name?");
                validated = false;
            } 
            if(lastnamejava.getText().toString().length() == 0) 
            { 
                lastnamejava.setError("Whats your last name?"); 
                validated = false;
            } 
            if(pickupaddressjava.getText().toString().length() == 0) 
            { 
                pickupaddressjava.setError("Enter your address"); 
                validated = false;
            } 
            if(postalcodejava.getText().toString().length() < 6) 
            { 
                postalcodejava.setError("Invalid postal code"); 
                validated = false;
            } 
            if(pickuptimejava.getText().toString().length() == 0) 
            { 
                pickuptimejava.setError("Enter pickuptime"); 
                validated = false;
            } 
            if(numberstuffjava.getText().toString().length() == 0) { 
                numberstuffjava.setError("Enter number of clothes"); 
                validated = false;
            } 

            // fire in the hole !
            if (validated) 
            { 
                addInfo(); 
                Intent nextpageintent = new Intent(Afterfullscreen.this, Extrainformation.class);
                startActivity(nextpageintent);
            } 



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The else condition it's only attached to the numberstuffjava if condition, in this scenario the else condition will be called always when this if condition is false.
Try changing the previous if conditions with else if.

Answer (score 0):

You just create a method which return `true` only if all your needs are satisfied. if the method return `true`, then only go to next activity. I will give an example here.

```
public boolean isValid(){
    if(phnumberjava.getText().toString().length() < 10)
            {
                phnumberjava.setError("Invalid Phone Number");
                return false;
            }
            if(firstnamejava.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            {
                firstnamejava.setError("Whats your first name?");
                return false;
            }
    return true;
}
```

Then do things like below.

```
if(isValid()){
      addInfo();
      Intent nextpageintent = new Intent(Afterfullscreen.this, Extrainformation.class);
      startActivity(nextpageintent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add else if for checking all validation

```
   if (v == nextbuttonjava) {
                if (edittext1.getText().toString().length() < 5) {
                    edittext1.setError("error");
                } else if (edittext2.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    edittext2.setError("error");
                } else {
     //                       your intent here
                }

            }
```

add else if for every of your edittext .

Answer (score 0):

Try out below method to check an empty value of edittext.

```
public static boolean m_isError = false;

    /**
     * This is method to check edit text empty or not.
     * 
     * @param p_editText
     *            - edittext
     * @param p_nullMsg
     *            -display message if edittext null
     */
    public static void validateForEmptyValue(EditText p_editText,
            String p_nullMsg) {
        if (p_editText != null && p_nullMsg != null) {
            // use trim() while checking for blank values
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(p_editText.getText().toString().trim())) {
                m_isError = true;
                p_editText.setError(p_nullMsg);
            }
        }
    }
```

Use the above method as below for each of your edittext:

```
 CustomValidator.m_isError = false;

                CustomValidator.validateForEmptyValue(metfirstname, "enter firstname", metfirstname);
CustomValidator.validateForEmptyValue(metlastname, "enter lastname", metlastname);

           if (!CustomValidator.m_isError) {
          //Define your logic once all the validations are done.

             addInfo();
            Intent nextpageintent = new Intent(Afterfullscreen.this, Extrainformation.class);
            startActivity(nextpageintent);
}
```